# How to access selenium grid from Azure Virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, selenium-grid

I newbie to azure devops and trying to spinning up a selenium grid on azure VM. I am able to start selenium grid and  nodes on azure VM but while accessing them through my windows local machine I am facing issue.

Your help would be much appreciated, Thanks

Hub :

```
azureuser@VirtualMachine01:~$ java -jar selenium-server-4.10.0.jar  hub --port 4444
20:30:32.224 INFO [LogManager$RootLogger.log] - Using the system default encoding
20:30:32.233 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
20:30:32.456 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442, advertising as tcp://10.1.0.3:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, advertising as tcp://10.1.0.3:4443]
20:30:32.608 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://10.1.0.3:4442 and tcp://10.1.0.3:4443
20:30:32.645 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
20:30:33.655 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
20:30:34.893 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium Hub 4.10.0 (revision c14d967899): http://10.1.0.3:4444
20:31:56.639 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative
20:31:57.847 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching Node 99076e26-e828-4bb5-9cc8-cf4e65bfd652 (uri: http://10.1.0.3:5555) from DOWN to UP
20:31:57.848 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node 99076e26-cfdf44-cfdf44-9cc8-cf4e65bfd652 at http://10.1.0.3:5555. Health check every 120s
```

Node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.10.0.jar node
20:31:54.346 INFO [LogManager$RootLogger.log] - Using the system default encoding
20:31:54.355 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
20:31:54.697 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://0.0.0.0:4442 and tcp://0.0.0.0:4443
20:31:54.821 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
20:31:55.823 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
20:31:55.974 INFO [NodeServer.createHandlers] - Reporting self as: http://10.1.0.4:5555
20:31:56.024 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 1 available processors
20:31:56.035 INFO [NodeOptions.discoverDrivers] - Driver(s) already present on the host: 1
20:31:56.110 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Chrome for {"browserName": "chrome","goog:chromeOptions": {"args": ["--remote-allow-origins=*"]},"platformName": "linux"} 1 times (Host)
20:31:56.143 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative
20:31:56.481 INFO [NodeServer$1.start] - Starting registration process for Node http://10.1.0.4:5555
20:31:56.483 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Started Selenium node 4.10.0 (revision c14d967899): http://10.1.0.4:5555
20:31:56.524 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
20:31:57.910 INFO [NodeServer.lambda$createHandlers$2] - Node has been added
```

Azure :

[image]